# Remove/hide subdirectory from URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

Currently `www.brand-a.com` and `www.brand-b.com` both point to the root folder containing a HTML landing page directing users to either `/siteA` or `/siteB` both of which contain an installation of WordPress containing the content relevant to each brand.

```
- root
  |- index.html (landing page)
  |- /siteA/
    |- WordPress
  |- /siteB/
    |- WordPress
```

The landing page (index.html) is currently accessible from either `brand-a.com or brand-b.com` with the main sites are being accessible from `brand-a.com/siteA` and `brand-b.com/siteB`

Given the current set up is it possible to remove/hide the subdirectories `/siteA` and `/siteB` from the URL via .htaccess or would this just redirect everything back to the landing page?

Would it be best to have a third domain to act as a bridge between the two brands?

For example

```
www.brand-bridge.com -> /index.html (landing page)
www.brand-a.com -> /siteA/
www.brand-b.com -> /siteB/
```

This would keep each area separate and allow the domains to point directly at their respective content.

Ultimately just trying to determine if this is even possible and what my options are, if you require any further information please let me know and I'll answer as best I can.

Thanks

**Edit:** The client as requested both `www.brand-a.com` and `www.brand-b.com` go to the landing page giving the user the option which site they would like to access regardless of which URL is used.

Answer (score 0):

/* you can use any domain mapping plugin or redirection plugin for both site and redirect to original domain */

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer. If I were to redirect `www.brand-a.com/siteA/` to `www.brand-a.com` it would just end up back at the landing page making the WordPress installation inaccessible?

Comment: in domain mapping plugin, it will redirect front URL only and backed will same as it is

Comment: Front URL? Are you suggesting I redirect `www.brand-a.com/siteA` to `www.brand-a.com`?

Comment: As mentioned in my original post `www.brand-a.com` and `www.brand-b.com` both point to the root folder containing the landing page, if I were to redirect `www.brand-a.com/siteA` to `www.brand-a.com` trying to access the WordPress installation in the subdirectory `/siteA` would redirect to the landing page would it not?